# Back to the sqlplus prompt

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm a beginner in PL/SQL, I'm trying some sql script but sometimes I have an error in my script and the prompt doesn't appear; I remain in input mode.

How can I retrieve the prompt without shutting down the terminal?

(p.s.: I used sql plus for oracle 11g under Ubuntu OS)

Comment: Aside: I've enjoyed using [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html)

Comment: What do you mean by 'input mode' - are you getting a numbered prompt, and are you writing a PL/SQL block?

Comment: Hi Alex,input mode means that i get a numbered prompt,yes i'm writing a pl/sql block

Comment: Then you did not end your statements with either a ; or /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039663)

> SQL*Plus treats PL/SQL subprograms in the same manner as SQL commands, except that a semicolon (;) or a blank line does not terminate and execute a block. Terminate PL/SQL subprograms by entering a period (.) by itself on a new line. You can also terminate and execute a PL/SQL subprogram by entering a slash (/) by itself on a new line.

If you're entering a PL/SQL block and getting numbered prompts, enter a period (`.`) on its own and you'll drop back to the `SQL>` prompt.

```
SQL> declare
  2
  3
  4
  5  .
SQL>
```

The code you entered will still be in the buffer and you can run it with `/`, or edit it in your configured text editor with `edit`. (You can set that with `define _editor = "/usr/bin/vim"`, for example).